# how to decode a json to an struct/class object having space in their keys?

Tags: ios, json, swift, objective-c, swift3

Hello I have a json object like this

```
{
    "ID NATION":  "US"
    "ID YEAR"  :  "1995"
}
```

I am trying to convert it in to an struct object in swift

```
struct Details
{
   var ID NATION:
}
```

Since variables cannot have spaces how can I declare the variables in swift corresponding to keys having spaces in JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CodingKeys` to map JSON keys to variables.

```
    var idNation: String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case idNation = "ID Nation"
    }
```